# Unexpected empty writestream in collectionFS using graphicsmagick

Tags: javascript, meteor, graphicsmagick, collectionfs

I'm using CollectionFS for managing images. Furthermore I'm using graphicsmagick `gm()` for manipulating images.

Now I want to crop a already saved image. Therefore on a click event a server-method is called, which does the crop(). But after doing this, in the collection I find an empty image with `size=0` updated on the correct date.

I don't see, what I am doing wrong.

**shared.js**

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
    stores: [
        new FS.Store.FileSystem("thumbnail", { 
            transformWrite: function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
                gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).autoOrient().resize('96', '96' + '^').gravity('Center').extent('96', '96').stream().pipe(writeStream);
            } 
        }),
        new FS.Store.FileSystem("public"),
    ]
});
```

**server.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    'crop': function (fileId, selection) {
        var file = Images.findOne({ _id: fileId }),
            read = file.createReadStream('public'),
            write = file.createWriteStream('public');

        gm(read)
            .crop(selection.width, selection.height, selection.left, selection.top)
        .stream()
        .pipe(write);
    }
});
```

**client.js**

```
Template.editor.events({
    'click #crop': function () { 
        var fileId      = '123456789',
            selection   = { height: 100, width: 100, top: 10, left: 10 }; 

        Meteor.call('crop', fileId, selection);
    }
});
```

**Update**

As recommended by Christian I'm using a tmp-file for the writeStream, because the writeStream can't be the same like the readStream - which caused the empty result.

But after writing to the tmp-file, the content of it has to be copied back to the public store. How do I do that?

```
Meteor.methods({
    'crop': function (fileId, selection) {

        var fs   = Meteor.npmRequire('fs'),
            file = Images.findOne({ _id: fileId }),
            read = file.createReadStream('public'),
            filename = '/tmp/gm_' + Date.now(),
            tmp  = fs.createWriteStream(filename);

        gm(read)
            .crop(selection.width, selection.height, selection.left, selection.top)
        .stream()
        .pipe(tmp);

        // After writing to tmp -> copy back to stream and delete tmp-file
    }
});
```

**Update 2**
I tried this one:

```
// Add temp store
new FS.Store.FileSystem("temp")

// Method
Meteor.methods({
    'crop': function (fileId, selection) {
        var file  = Images.findOne({ _id: fileId }),
            read  = file.createReadStream('public'),
            temp  = file.createWriteStream('temp');

        gm(read)
            .crop(selection.width, selection.height, selection.left, selection.top)
        .stream()
        .pipe(tmp)
        .on('end', function () {
            var tmpread  = file.createReadStream('temp'),
                write    = file.createWriteStream('public');

            gm(tmpread).stream().pipe(write);
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't read and write into the same file. This is equivalent to things like

```
cat test | grep 1 > test
```

on the shell. You can try it and see that `test` will be empty afterwards.

You need to create an intermediate, temporary file in your `crop` method.

---

Assuming that is indeed the problem, then this is one way of doing this (not tested):

```
var fs = Meteor.npmRequire('fs');
var file = Images.findOne({ _id: fileId }),
var read = file.createReadStream('public'),
var filename = '/tmp/gm_' + Date.now();
var tmp = fs.createWriteStream(filename);

var gmread = gm(read)
    .crop(selection.width, selection.height, selection.left, selection.top)
    .stream();

gmread.on('end', function() {
    // done streaming through GM, copy the result back:
    var tmpread = fs.createReadStream(filename);
    var write = file.createWriteStream('public');
    tmpread.pipe(write);
});

gmread.pipe(tmp);
```

Comment: So what is the difference to this? https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/wiki/How-to:-Convert-a-file-already-stored

Comment: have you tried that and does it work? I'm not an expert at streams, but the way I understand them it might be luck if it did -- it may work for small files that get buffered as a whole before writing out from the buffer begins, but not for larger ones. But who knows, maybe collectionfs does something smart internally to allow this. One way or another, I don't think I would rely on that. Let me know what you find out when you test this.

Comment: Hmm.. could you please give an example how you would use a temporary stream?

Comment: How do I copy `tmp`to `write` after it is done and empty `tmp`?

Comment: really? You are asking for all this extra work and you haven't even up-voted or accepted the answer? I'm sure you'll find the answer to that last question somewhere. It's just copying a file into a stream which you already have ;-)

Comment: I'm very sorry for that stupid question. But I tried to get this in the last 24 hours, but I don't get it. Of course I will accept the answer - as I always do -, but I just want to get the thing working. Please don't mind...

Comment: I would like to give you a bounty for helping to get this thing work. It is just for copy and removing the temp stream...

Comment: oh wow, thanks! I guess you are really stuck on this, eh? Well I added some code along those lines. Please let me know if it's working. I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Need to use `var fs = Npm.require('fs');` for Meteor 1.2. P.S.: I can give you the bounty in 15 hours...

Comment: `Npm.require` is for packages, in projects themselves you should use `Meteor.npmRequire` provided by the `meteorhacks:npm` package.

Comment: Yes, it is working. I accepted your answer. And I will give you the bounty as soon as possible.

Comment: But I had to use `Meteor.bindEnvironment()`. Maybe you want to add this to your answer.

Comment: oh really? sure, I can add it. For which part was that required?